# Why is it called an "orthocenter"? What is the orthocircle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

We know that the orthocenter of a triangle is the place where the triangle's three altitudes intersect. But why is it called that?

The *in*center - the intersection of the triangle's three angle bisectors - is the center of the *in*scribed circle.

The *circum*center - the intersection of the triangle's three perpendicular bisectors - is the center of the *circum*scribed circle.

But what is an "orthocircle" (if such exists)?

[This document](http://www.math.washington.edu/~king/coursedir/m445w06/ortho/01-05-orthog.html) says that two circles could be orthogonal. Well gee, whiz!

[This one](http://pygeo.sourceforge.net/docs/class-base.geometry_real.circles.OrthoCircle.html) says an orthocircle has the given center and is orthogonal to the given circle. That doesn't help, because I can make an orthogonal circle to the triangle from many points (maybe even all of them).

And according to [Wolframalpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Orthocenter.html), the name "orthocenter" was invented by people named Besant and Ferrers. But that page doesn't indicate why how came up with it.

And that is literally everything I could find on the word "orthocircle" or on "why is it called orthocenter?".

So why is it called "orthocenter"? And what is the "orthocircle"?

P.S. And how do I *italicize* part of a word?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I believe it is because orthocenter is formed form dropping three altitudes, which by definition makes an angle of $90^0$ with its opposite base.

Comment: *Ortho-* because orthogonal means perpendicular, *-center* because it is a [triangle center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_center) (which is not necessarily the center of any useful circle).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Ortho* means "straight, right". Orthocenter, because it is the intersection of the lines passing through the vertices and forming *right*-angles with the opposite sides.

There are many circumferences associated to the orthocenter. I don't think (or better said I haven't heard of) any of them called orthocircle.

Nevertheless, the *orthocenter* **is the center of the circle** that passes through the vertices of the *anticomplementary triangle* (it is the circumcenter of the *anticomplementary triangle*). The *anticomplementary triangle* has sides passing through the vertices of the triangle, parallel to the opposite sides.

[image: Anticomplementary triangle]

Equivalently the original triangle has vertices at the midpoints of the sides of the anticomplementary triangle. Maybe this could be called the *orthocircle*.

Also, if you take a circle with its radius being half the circumradius of the triangle and with center halfway between the orthocentre and the circumcenter, we get the **nine-point circle**. This circle passes through the feet of the altitudes, the mid-points of the sides, and the mid-points between the orthocenter and the vertices.

[image: Nine-point circle]

In the picture above, $H$ is the orthocenter, $O$ is the circumcenter, and $G$ is the center of the nine-point circle, which is halfway between $H$ and $O$.

The *nine-point circle* is $1/4$ times contraction of the circumcenter of the anticomplementary triangle, again a contraction with center at the orthocenter. Equivalently, the circumcenter of the anticomplementary triangle is the $2$ times expansion of the circumcenter of the original triangle, by a contraction again with center at the orthocenter.

Comment: In the nine-point circle, where do you get the points labelled Ea, Eb and Ec ?

Comment: @Kantura I guess, by looking at the figure, Ea is midpoint of AH, Eb is midpoint of BH and Ec is midpoint of CH.